# Is there an easier way than this to edit a table in my database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-express

I’m trying to update a row in a table. I found a way to make it work but I’m wondering if there is an easier or better way.  Please help me with any ideas that you may have. Thanks

Here’s the code…

```
   var courseRubics = from r in db.Rubrics where r.DepartmentID == 2 select r;
        var selectedRubrics = courseRubics.Select(r => r.RubricID);
        List<int> rubricsList = selectedRubrics.ToList();


        foreach (var rub in courseRubics.ToList())

        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(formCollection["item.Weight"]))
            {
                Rubric aRubic1 = db.Rubrics.Find(1);
                Rubric updateRubic1 = (Rubric)aRubic1;
                int rubric1 = Convert.ToInt32(totlrubric[0]);
                updateRubic1.Weight = rubric1;

                Rubric aRubic2 = db.Rubrics.Find(2);
                Rubric updateRubic2 = (Rubric)aRubic2;
                int rubric2 = Convert.ToInt32(totlrubric[1]);
                updateRubic2.Weight = rubric2;

                Rubric aRubic3 = db.Rubrics.Find(4);
                Rubric updateRubic3 = (Rubric)aRubic3;
                int rubric3 = Convert.ToInt32(totlrubric[2]);
                updateRubic3.Weight = rubric3;



            }


            db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas / observations

1. Your initial set of selects could be narrowed down to (sorry for the alternate syntax)

   ```
   var list = db.Rubrics.Where(r => r.DepartmentId == 2).Select(x => x.RubricId).ToList()
   ```
2. You iterate over `foreach (var rub in courseRubics.ToList())` but don't seem to be doing anything with `rub`
3. The contents of the `if...` could be tightened up a little.  I don't see any reason why you need to do the casting or why you can't just inline the creation of rubricX,

   ```
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(formCollection["item.Weight"]))
       {
           Rubric aRubic1 = db.Rubrics.Find(1);
           aRubic1.Weight = Convert.ToInt32(totlrubric[0]);

           Rubric aRubic2 = db.Rubrics.Find(2);
           aRubic2.Weight = Convert.ToInt32(totlrubric[1]);

           Rubric aRubic3 = db.Rubrics.Find(4);
           aRubic3.Weight = Convert.ToInt32(totlrubric[2]);
       }
   ```

Comment: I tried something like this foreach (var rub in sellectedRubrics.Select((x, i) => new { Data = x, Index = i })){Rubric r=(Rubric)rub;} got conversion error message.